# Join with MAX date in range

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables: `DEAL` and `DEPTH` (history of departments)

```
SELECT *
  FROM deal
       LEFT JOIN depth
         ON (    deal.dept_gid = depth_gid
             AND deal.deal_begin_date <= depth_end_date
             AND deal.deal_end_date >= depth_start_date)
```

But if there more that one row in `DEPTH` that meets condition "same `dept_gid` and ranges must intersect" then I need to return row with maximum `depth_end_date`. How can I do it?

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result ? that really help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using row number here:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT d1.*, d2.*,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY d1.dept_gid ORDER BY d2.depth_end_date DESC) rn
    FROM deal d1
    LEFT JOIN depth d2
        ON d1.dept_gid = d2.depth_gid AND
           d1.deal_begin_date <= d2.depth_end_date AND
           d1.deal_end_date >= d2.depth_start_date
) t
WHERE rn = 1
```

Comment: Thank you, I just changed PARTITION BY, moved this join in WITH clause and then add other joins